# jQuery lazyload on carouFredSel

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, lazy-loading

Im using [jquery lazyload](http://view-source:https://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/jquery.lazyload.js?v=1.9.1) to load my images

but a part of my website has [carouFredSel](https://github.com/Codeinwp/carouFredSel-jQuery)

when i click on next button the next images are not loaded because require to scroll the page, so is there any way to get images loaded on every slide?

```
jQuery(".foo4").carouFredSel({
        auto: !1,
        prev: ".prev4",
        next: ".next4",
        pagination: ".pager4",
        mousewheel: !0,
        swipe: {
            onMouse: !0,
            onTouch: !0
        }
    }),
```

above code is the javascript to slide the carousel and below I have my lazyscript

```
jQuery("img.lazy").lazyload();
```

Any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In carouFredSel, you provide the image **url** in **data-src** like

```
<img data-src="image-url"/>
```

So to show the image in you need to configure, in OnBefore of carouFredSel like.

```
scroll: {
   onBefore: function( data ) {
      var $current = data.items.visible.first(),
          visible = data.items.visible,
          src = visible.data('src');

      visible.attr('src', src);
    }
}
```

Add this lines in your carouFredSel code like

```
jQuery(".foo4").carouFredSel({
        auto: !1,
        prev: ".prev4",
        next: ".next4",
        pagination: ".pager4",
        mousewheel: !0,
        swipe: {
            onMouse: !0,
            onTouch: !0
        },
        scroll: {
          onBefore: function( data ) {
            var $current = data.items.visible.first(),
               visible = data.items.visible,
               src = visible.data('src');

            visible.attr('src', src);
         }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I added it below the line 1022 on jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1.js but its breaking the carousel

Comment: you don't need to change anything in your carouFredSel plugin. You need to change only carouFredSel configuration in your page js file. Check above.

Comment: Yes I tried this one too also I copied and pasted this time as your edit but the same now its breaking the carousel so every click is pushing me to the top maybe there is a syntax error?

Comment: I just changed `scroll {` to `scroll: {` now the carousel worked but it doesnt load images on slides again :(

Comment: can you put your code in **codpen** or **jsfiddle**

Answer (score 0):

I believe I solved this issue for lazy loading images with caroufredsel

```
$('#youtube-playlist').carouFredSel({
    width: '100%',
    height: "variable",
    circular: false,
    infinite: false,
    responsive: true,
    items: {
        visible: {
            min: 2,
            max: 4
        }
    },
    onCreate: function(data) {
        // Swap data-src for first 4 items
        // console.log(data);
        $(this).find("img[data-src]").each(function (i, item) {
            $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('data-src')).removeAttr('data-src');
            return i < data.items.length-1;
        });
    },
    scroll: {
        onBefore: function(data) { 
            // Lazyload next visible thumbnails
            // console.log(data.items.visible.length);
            for ( i = 0; i < data.items.visible.length; i++ ) {
                var $img = data.items.visible.eq(i).find('img');
                $img.attr('src', $img.attr('data-src') ).removeAttr('data-src');
            }
        }
    },
    align: 'center',
    auto: false,
    prev: '#prev',
    next: '#next'
});
```

1. **onCreate** : find first visible images and swap data-src to src attribute.
2. **Scroll onBefore** : Iterate through the next visible items and swap attributes.

Inspect the Network [filter img] tab in chrome dev tools and watch as the lazyload happens.

I tried adding a width value to my items to remove the console log notice from caroufredsel but it doesn't like the lazyload onCreate.